# Using Bluetooth to on water pump with MIT app inventor 2

Tags: bluetooth, arduino, sensors

I have a school project whereby I have to sense the parameters of temperature and humidity using the dht sensor and transfer the data via bluetooth hc05 to an android device using MIT App Inventor 2.

From the application, the user can turn on the pump when he or she clicks on "pump on" and off the pump when he or she click on "pump off".

Currently, I am able to sense the temperature and humidity and transfer the data via bluetooth to display on the application.

```html
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <dht.h>
dht DHT;
#define DHT11_PIN 6

int bluetoothTx = 10; // bluetooth tx to 10 pin
int bluetoothRx = 11; // bluetooth rx to 11 pin

SoftwareSerial bluetooth(bluetoothTx, bluetoothRx);
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);

  bluetooth.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
 int chk = DHT.read11(DHT11_PIN);
{
    //Serial.print("Temperature = ");
  bluetooth.print(DHT.temperature,1);
  bluetooth.print("|");
  //Serial.print("Humidity = ");
  bluetooth.print(DHT.humidity,1);
  bluetooth.println("|");
  delay(1000);
}
}
```

[My MIT app inventor block code but i do not know how to code on the arduino as well as connect the circuit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEaxQ.png)

However, I am having difficulties connecting the circuit on the arduino for the bluetooth, dht sensor and water pump as well as coding it out.

Appreciate if experts could help out, this is my first time coding TT